Error running project on M2 Pro Command PhaseScriptExecution failed
I have a problem with an old native iOS app.
The application was created on iMac with an Intel processor and the project works properly on such a computer, but when I try to build the project on  Mac Mini with M2 Pro, the error

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

is displayed
I see the error Pods/R.swift/rswift: Bad CPU type in executable . How do I fix it?

That’s a pretty generic error message, it’s either caused by a script you wrote or a 3rd party framework. You need to do some more research

I see the error  Pods/R.swift/rswift: Bad CPU type in executable . How do I fix it?

You should add that information to the question and maybe someone can help you with it.
